# Convert nested JSON to XLSX using C#

Tags: c#, json, converters, xlsx

I am looking to convert some sort of JSON file into XLSX... Here is the code I have so far...

```
    [
    {
      "F1": 1,
      "F2": 2,
      "F3": [
        {
          "E1": 3,
          "E2": 4
        },
        {
          "E1": 5,
          "E2": 6
        },
        {
          "E1": 7,
          "E2": 8,
          "E3": [
            {
              "D1": 9,
              "D2": 10
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
}   
]
```

That is the JSON file.

```
  public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\JSON\";
            var x = Deserializing(path);
            XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();

            wb.Worksheets.Add(x, "New");
            wb.SaveAs(path + "Testing3.xlsx", true);

            Console.WriteLine("Files succesfully converted...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static DataTable Deserializing(string pat)
        {
            DataTable table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(File.ReadAllText(pat + "test1.json"));

            return table;
        }
    }
}
```

However this is all that returned...

```
F1 F2 F3
1  2
```

I want it to look like this...

```
F1,F2,E1,E2,D1,D2
1,2
1,2,3,4
1,2,5,6
1,2,7,8,9,10
```

It completely stopped after the F3 (probably due to the square bracket? Help!